# I would like 2 HTML/CSS divs placed next to each other (tried other methods), (Also format in divs)

Tags: html, css, position, format

**FIDDLE:**

**http://jsfiddle.net/z7tyW/**

Here is my code:

```
    <div id="container">
    <div id="header">
<img align="center" src="images/image.png" />
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="slogan">
    <h2>Some Text</h2>
    </div>
<div id="login">
        <form name="loginForm" action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check'/>" method="post">
        Enter User Name: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
        Enter Password: <input name="password" type="password"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="register">
      <a href="register.php"><img align="center" src="images/signup.png" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
    #container {width: 800px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position: relative;}
    #header {width: 800px;
    height: 260px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align:center; }

    #wrapper {
    width: 800px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top: 80px;
    }

    #slogan {width: 100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align: center;
    border:2px solid;}

    #login { width: 399px;
    height:200px;
    float: left;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    border:2px solid;
    text-align:center;text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }

    #register { width: 393px;
    height:200px;
    float:right;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    border:2px solid;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 200px;}
```

Now I have tried many methods I've found on here. I am using google chrome. When using this method, the edges of the borders of login and registration, don't line up with the Slogan. The other methods I have tried, I end up with the registration still below login. Or the otherway around. I want those divs to be, together the same length as slogan and, directly next to each other so they are all snug up with slogan and touching each other's borders.

Any ideas?
Thanks guys!

Also, I would like the login form to be at the center both vertically and horizantally. Same with the registration div. This will allow me to both both images in there!

Thanks again!

Comment: Make a fiddle of you code please

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QSgM5/ Once the image is exactly on the right div, it then doesn't align center. I would rather not use tables unless I have to.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6Z9vm/ See?

Comment: do you want your page in the center ? you wrote lot of bad css

Comment: I want the slogan, beneath the header. Then aligned center with register and login, directly beneath it. With them next to each other, equal lengths and in-line with Slogan.

Comment: okay let me refactor your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**fiddle:**

**http://jsfiddle.net/Q9uQP/1/**

**HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title id='title'>HTML Page setup Tutorial</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $.fn.center = function(parent) {
                this.css("position", "relative");
                this.css("top", ($(parent).height() - this.height()) / 2 + "px");
                this.css("left", ($(parent).width() - this.width()) / 2 + "px");
                return this;
            };
            $(function() {
                $('#loginForm').center("#login");
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header">
                <img align="center" src="images/image.png" />
            </div>
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="slogan">
                    <h2>Some Text</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="main">
                    <div id="login">
                        <form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check'/>" method="post">
                            Enter User Name: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
                            Enter Password: <input name="password" type="password"><br>
                            <input type="submit" value="Login">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div id="register">
                        <a href="register.php"><img align="center" src="images/signup.png" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**style.css:**

```
body{
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

#container {
    width: 800px;
    margin:auto;
}

#header {
    width: 800px;
    height: 260px;
    margin:auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align:center; 
}

#wrapper {
    width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 80px;
}

#slogan {
    margin:auto;
    text-align: center;
    border:2px solid;
}
.main{
    background:#efefef;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#login { 
    width: 396px;
    height:200px;
    float: left;
    border:2px solid;
    text-align:center;        

}
#register {
    width: 396px;
    height:200px;
    border:2px solid;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float:left;
}
```

instead of the below line you direct download jquery from the website and include it in your project and give the relative path to it:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

just save this code and include in your project:

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js

Comment: It's worked thank you! Curious though, I've never really done jquery. Not sure where to add it.

Comment: Hmm it's not working locally. I've tried pushing it to heroku like my original idea but still nothing. The login is not central.

Comment: Did you change the jQuery to js/jquery.js ..download jQuery first

Comment: Check your console in browser and tell me the error